# django ajax request dont get data

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

```
<form id="searchform">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input  type="text" id="question" class="form-control" placeholder="question......"
         name="question">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  value="ASK">
    </div>
<form>
```

I have this template and bellow ajax request to get data to view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#searchform").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "results",
            data:{
                input:$("#question").val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success : function(data){
                $('#answer').html(data);
            }
        },"json");
    });
});
</script>
```

and view is below

```
def results(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        resource = request.POST['input']
    return render(request, 'index.html',{"resource" : resource})
```

the thing i sumbit in form can be seen in url.but does not print result in template.What is the problem in this code?thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues i see with the way i see you writing this code. Ajaxifying form submits are trivial and can be done very elegantly.

Let me explain  based on code you shared.

First your form doesn't have action and method. A properly defined form should work even when the browser doesn't support javascript.

One of your form form fields doesn't have a name parameter.

```
<form id="searchform" method="POST" action="{% url 'results' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input  type="text" id="question" name="input" class="form-control" placeholder="question......"
         name="question">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  value="ASK">
    </div>
<form>
```

Now in your javascript You just add a override and prevent the default behaviour. This is reason your page is changing just url .

A more generic version. See you don't have to form data payload and others as well.

```
$(document).on('submit', "#searchform", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var ele = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: ele.attr("method"),
    url: ele.attr("action"),
    data: ele.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
       $('#answer').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

I don't see a issue with your views as such.

Answer (score 0):

Return a [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) object in your view:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def results(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        resource = request.POST['input']
    return JsonResponse({"resource" : resource})
```

Comment: it doesnt print data.but in url it shows the entered data.And i want to print data in template

Comment: In your javascript, in the `success` function, add the following: `$('#answer').html(data.resource);`

Answer (score 0):

Your form get's submitted via GET method and GET parameteres(default behavior of forms).
To fix this and make your code work - simply prevent that default behavior

```
$("#searchform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventdefault();
    ...
}
```